# Use PathElement in objectify query as ancestor

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine, objectify

I am migrating from google datastore api to objectify(i have used datastore at compute engine and migrating to 6.0a1 objectify). In previous version i used this code to query users:

```
KeyFactory userKeyFactory = datastore.newKeyFactory()
    .addAncestors(PathElement.of("UserList", "default"))
    .setKind(USER_KIND);

//...save entity

Query<Entity> query = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
    .setKind(USER_KIND)
    .setFilter(PropertyFilter.hasAncestor(datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind("UserList").newKey("default")))
    .build();
QueryResults<Entity> queryResults = datastore.run(query);
List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();
queryResults.forEachRemaining(entity -> result.add(transformUser(entity)));
return result;
```

Now i am trying to make same query with ancestor. However objectify don't work with `PathElement`. So following code:

```
ofy().load().type(User.class).ancestor(PathElement.of("UserList", "default")).list()
```

fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class 'com.google.cloud.datastore.PathElement' was registered
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Registrar.getMetadataSafe(Registrar.java:115)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.getMetadataSafe(Keys.java:56)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.getMetadataSafe(Keys.java:65)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.rawKeyOf(Keys.java:47)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.anythingToRawKey(Keys.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl.setAncestor(QueryImpl.java:203)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.SimpleQueryImpl.ancestor(SimpleQueryImpl.java:69)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadTypeImpl.ancestor(LoadTypeImpl.java:23)
```

What is proper way to use PathElement with objectify? I see i can create `com.googlecode.objectify.Key` and pass it as ancestor but it require class, but i don't have `UserList` class (it is small application, all entities related to single group).

I tried to use this code:

`ofy().load().type(User.class).ancestor(datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind("UserList").newKey("default")).list()`

Now it fails that User don't have field with `@Parent` annotation. Here is stacktrace:

```
com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading Key{projectId=projectId, namespace=, path=[PathElement{kind=UserList, id=null, name=default}, PathElement{kind=User, id=1, name=null}]}: Loaded Entity has parent but com.package.model.User has no @Parent
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.load(EntityMetadata.java:84)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine.load(LoadEngine.java:187)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:145)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:131)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$1.nowUncached(Round.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.HybridQueryResults.lambda$load$1(HybridQueryResults.java:87)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.transform(Iterators.java:757)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at com.google.common.collect.MultitransformedIterator.next(MultitransformedIterator.java:66)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$4.computeNext(Iterators.java:623)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:145)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.HybridQueryResults.hasNext(HybridQueryResults.java:92)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.IteratorFirstResult.nowUncached(IteratorFirstResult.java:31)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.LoadResult.now(LoadResult.java:25)
    at com.package.UserObjectifyRepository.getUserByEmail(UserObjectifyRepository.java:43)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Loaded Entity has parent but com.package.model.User has no @Parent
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyMetadata.setKey(KeyMetadata.java:142)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyMetadata.setKey(KeyMetadata.java:122)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyPopulator.load(KeyPopulator.java:24)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.load(ClassPopulator.java:118)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.loadSafe(ClassTranslator.java:109)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.NullSafeTranslator.load(NullSafeTranslator.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.load(EntityMetadata.java:80)
    .. 125 more
```

I suppose correct way to fix this is to have parent field in my User entity, something like this:

```
@Parent
private UserList userList;
```

But i haven't such entity "UserList", i need ancestor just to make query with strong consistency.

UPD: Error is gone if i adding this code:

```
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Key;
@Parent
private Key userList;
```

Is it proper way to make consistent query?

Comment: What do you mean by "Now it fails that User don't have field with `@Parent` annotation"? The right answer is to provide a low-level Key as you describe.

Comment: Thanks for response @stickfigure, i will add stacktrace tomorrow, when will be near code.

Comment: @stickfigure i updated question

Answer (score 0):

The [@Parent annotation](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/AnnotationReference) requires a key.

You just have to create a key, so it can understand that Parent/Child relationship.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You are loading an entity from the datastore, but the POJO you're trying to load it into doesn't match the structure of the identity. Objectify is normally very forgiving about structure changes, but not when it comes to the identity fields (id and parent).